# Open-source projects that use Selenium webdriver C#?

Tags: open-source, c#, software-testing

We are getting started with UI tests for our web app, using Selenium C#. I'm interested in seeing how other people have approached this. For that reason, if there are C# open-source batteries of C# Selenium tests targeting other web projects, I'd be interested to see them.